# How to make @ngrx/store work with lazy loading on RC.6

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, redux, ngrx

I had a working Angular 2 RC.6 applications with lazy loading modules. I've add [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) and [ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects). I thought everything worked fine until I add [ngrx/store-devtools](https://github.com/ngrx/store-devtools) and [ngrx/store-log-monitor](https://github.com/ngrx/store-log-monitor).

I realised that even though http worked (and data received), **states were not used**.
After 1 full day of trying to understand why, **I realised it's because of lazy loading**.
[ngrx-exemple app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) is not using lazy loading.

And the only thing I've found about making ngrx/store work with lazy loading is [this](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/197) but I can't make it work.
And this does not include a SharedModule.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I feel like I should wait for next versions of ngrx suite. In order to keep working, I'm going to remove lazy loading for now. Lets hope Rob Wormald is going to talk about this in the next ng conf.

Comment: I just found this so I'm happy https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/211

Comment: I did not understand the problem. I am using @ngrx/store with lazy loading .

Comment: @Skeptor But are you doing it with multiple modules per the github line from Tom..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been implemented in v4 : https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/211#issuecomment-316253847